# Show information after record creation on ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to let the admin user see a particular message after or before or during he creats a new record.

I need either an alert box after he created the new record, or to change the current confirmation message just for the user model, or to add a small text in the form specifying this.

I can't seem to find any of the ways.

Thank you

Comment: if you are using something like devise for your authentication process, the password is encrypted, you can change it, but no display it. taking security seriously is better to create logic with a new attribute like "password_changed" that you control when the user change the password and then you can show something like "password for this user is the default" or "password is already changed"

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear. I don't want to show the password, just a message. The context of the message is nothing in particular. I just put it as an example of in what case I'm trying to display the information message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify the flash message with an after_create callback for that case, something like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  permit_params :name, :email, :password

    after_create do |user|
      flash[:notice] = "User has been created with the default password" if user.valid?
    end

end
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer. I just made a correction and added `if user.valid?` because else it displays the message even if some fields are invalid (I tried it. In the form it appears the message on top while some fields are highlited in red).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "notice:". In my case, after saving new "admin_user", I am checking for "resource". If it is "valid", then "redirect_to" with a "message". ... This always works for me.

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
 ....
 ....
     permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password

     def create
      @admin_user = AdminUser.new( admin_user_params )
      @admin_user.save

      if resource.valid?
        redirect_to collection_url, notice: 'Creation Success'
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Creation Failed'
        render :new
      end

    end

    private
      def admin_user_params
        params.require(:admin_user).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
      end

end
```

Comment: I like the solution so I'm upvoting but I think the other one is easier.

Comment: Thanks and you are right! My codes are from "old school programming"!